# Can someone explain to me how returns work under the hood in solidity?

Tags: solidity, evm, bytecode, bytes, yul

Can someone explain how I will be successfully able to return this

```
function reddish(uint256 _red) public view returns (bytes memory) {
    bytes memory err = abi.encode(msg.sender, _red);
    assembly {
        return(add(err, 32), mload(err))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i've found the answer to the question
https://twitter.com/AmadiMichaels/status/1619284675146686464?s=20